# Linear fit when distribution of errors is highly skewed

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, skewness, skew-normal-distribution

I have some datasets where the distribution of errors is expected to be highly skewed.  I'd like to do a linear fit that takes this into account.

Here is some synthetic data that shows this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000
slope = -30
x = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=2, size=n)
y1 = slope * x + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=100, size=n)
y2 = slope * x + scipy.stats.skewnorm.rvs(a=5, loc=0, scale=100, size=n)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(x,y1, alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(x,y2, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

My real data looks more similar to the orange points, not the blue points.  There's also a lot less of it, in some cases only 50-100 datapoints.  Of course I don't know that the distribution of errors is specifically skew normal - it could be better modelled by something else, eg exponentially modified Gaussian.

This is what the errors look like in the synthetic example above:
[image]

It seems when fitting a linear model to data like this, in some sense values to the left are more informative and should have a higher weight since the variance of the left half of the distribution is less.

Is there a way to do essentially a linear fit that assumes not a normal distribution of errors but some other distribution - in particular a highly skewed one?

Is it possible to simultaneously fit y=a*x+b and recover the shape of the error distribution?

Comment: You cannot legitimately call the orange terms "errors" because they are not centered around zero.  They would usually be conceived of as a sum of a *systematic* error (*aka* "bias") and a random component.  Agreed, they are still (a little skewed).  One usually handles with with a GLM, provided you have a sense of what distributional family the conditional responses come from.  If you really do have a systematic error component, then you need some independent means of estimating it: you can't obtain it from a regression model alone.

Comment: @whuber Yes, there is some bias, I didn’t try to subtract since that way the right half of the skew normal looks more obviously similar to the normal with same scale.  I’d like to ideally fit slope, loc, scale and a parameters to the data at the same time - bias the way you describe it (mean shift) depends on both loc, scale and a

Comment: Note that a linear fit (e.g., ordinary least squares) does *not* assume the errors are distributed Gaussian, nor does it assume any other distribution.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares for more.  The assumption of Gaussian errors leads to some stronger optimality properties than BLUE and known finite-sample properties as well.

Comment: @jbowman I’m not sure OLS is what I want (ie to minimize rms error in y).  I’d like to (at least) fit slope, loc and scale assuming a certain a value; but preferably fit slope, loc, scale and a.  “Fit” requires a bit of clarification too -  iin the limit of a very large amount of data generated by the code above, I’d like a method that can recover the values used to generate the data.  I don’t see any way OLS would do that, hence the question

Comment: If you fit these data without an intercept you will be using the wrong model and your predictions could be way off.  If you fit them with an intercept, you won't be able to distinguish the systematic bias from the intercept.  You have little hope even of "recovering the shape" unless you make some assumptions about that shape, such as limiting it to a finitely parameterized distribution family (which, if appropriately done, could handle the foregoing identifiability problem).

Comment: @whuber "unless you make some assumptions about that shape, such as limiting it to a finitely parameterized distribution family" - Indeed, that's what I thought.  Assuming a skew normal distribution (with unknown "a" parameter, but it could reasonably be around 3-5), how could the fit be done?

Comment: @jbowman On your comment "OLS does not assume the errors are distributed Gaussian" - the reason why I think OLS wouldn't work in this scenario is not exactly because of what it assumes about the errors, rather because it's not clear how to use it to fit the shape parameter of (eg) a skew normal distribution (or more generally, the parameters of any assumed error distribution).  Clearly assuming a specific value for shape changes the best fit for the intercept as well so both have to be fit at the same time, but how?

Comment: The usual way to conduct such fits is with maximum likelihood.  Other methods tend to emulate that approach by formulating objective functions which, when optimized, tend to produce good fits with large samples.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a linear model when a GLM like gamma regression explicitly models a skewed conditional distribution?

Comment: @Dave No reason, I'm just not familiar with the terminology.  I just mean a fit y=c1*x+c2+error_distribution(c3, ...) with some parameters c1, c2, c3, ... and error distribution.  The error doesn't seem to depend on x which I think is the main thing GLM tries to model (using the link function).  I think I need "something like GLM but where the error doesn't depend on x".

Comment: @Dave Gamma regression specifically probably won't work since the gamma distribution is defined on (0,+inf) whereas my errors look "normal-ish" on both sides of zero - yes they're skewed but they don't cut off at any particular value.

Comment: @whuber "The usual way to conduct such fits is with maximum likelihood" - Could you show an example of how to do that, eg for the data and distribution above?  In scipy, I can see scipy.stats.fit which does a MLE fit of the parameters of a distribution to data, but it's not clear how to fit the slope/intercept and parameters for the residuals using that.

Comment: Please see any of our discussions of GLMs, logistic regression, and related procedures: they are all carried out this way.

Comment: Looking at the raw data seems like the wrong perspective here. Is the skew still there in the residuals after fitting a model? Perhaps the explanatory variables would already explain why you see a skew in the unmodeled distribution of values.

Comment: @Björn “ Is the skew still there in the residuals after fitting a model?” Yes, definitely.  In the real data, just like in the synthetic data, there is a characteristic “crowding near the lower edge”, Residuals after OLS fit are very skewed as well

Comment: Why not just parametrize (the error distribution with some distribution) and (the linear curve) and infer the posterior of the parameters with MCMC? Or even better, use nested sampling to compare different hypotheses for the error distribution based on the evidence.

Comment: @marnix Sounds good, I just don't know how to do that. Could you post an answer with code?

Comment: I don't have the time for that, but see for example this tutorial in Python: https://johannesbuchner.github.io/UltraNest/example-sine-modelcomparison.html.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 cases:

1. If you do **not** know the type probability density distribution of the errors (i.e., the orange density plot), as you say, then I'd recommend to use a **robust** fitting procedure, such as Theil-Sen or RANSAC, rather than ordinary Least Squares (OLS). A robust estimator will reduce the chance that your estimation will go astray due to the unknown and skewed tails of the errors.
2. However, if you do know the type of probability density distribution of the errors (i.e., the orange density plot), then theoretically you can do much better by using Maximum Likelihood. Assume the errors are distributed according to a known probability density $f(\epsilon; \theta)$, where $\epsilon$ are the error values and $\theta$ are a set of parameters of the family of the distribution $f$. What you need to do is mathematically express the errors and parameters as a linear regression model (as implied by the scatter-plot), and estimate all unknown parameters using Maximum Likelihood. To clarify this, see the example below.

Example for clarifying the 2nd case:

Let's assume the known type of probability density distribution of the errors is an exponential distribution, which is obviously skewed in one direction, so: $$f(\epsilon; \theta) = \theta \exp({-\theta \cdot \epsilon}) \cdot U(\epsilon)$$
where $U(\epsilon)$ is the Heavyside step function, which is zero for negative $\epsilon$ and 1 otherwise.

But we need to somehow incorporate the linear regression model implied by the scatter-plot, so for this example, I've chosen to assume: $y = a \cdot x + b + \epsilon$, where $(x, y)$ are the horizontal and vertical coordinates of a specific data-point. The error term $\epsilon$ between the $y$-axis of a data-point and its linear model is then: $\epsilon = y - (a \cdot x + b) = y - ax - b$.

Plugging this into the probability density distribution of the error for a single data-point at $(x, y)$, we have the likelihood: $$f(x, y; \theta, a, b) = \theta \exp({-\theta \cdot (y - ax - b)}) \cdot U(y - ax - b)$$ $$= \theta \exp({-\theta y + \theta ax + \theta b}) \cdot U(y - ax - b)$$
where all unknown parameters which we'll need to estimate are: $\theta, a, b$.

Let's further assume the errors $\epsilon_n$ are statistically independent for each point $(x_n, y_n)$ of the $N$ data-points, so the joint probability density of the complete dataset $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ of $N$ data-points is: $$f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}; \theta, a, b) = \prod_{n=1..N}{f(x_n, y_n; \theta, a, b)}$$
In order to prodceed, it would be extremely convenient to take the (natural) logarithm, so we'll have a log-likelihood function. The log-likelihood function is differentiated with respect to the unknown parameters $\theta, a, b$ in order to maximize it for the given data-points.

An iterative numerical procedure is necessary for maximization in this specific example; perhaps it will also be necessary to run it from different initializations in order to guarantee that the discovered maximum is the global one.